# Can a line start from an adjacent square?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, area-of-effect

The below picture is from page 456 of CBR. Even after reading the sections *Areas* and *Line*, I am still unsure where the caster can place a *line*.

Position **A** is obviously fine for the caster, but what about **B** and **C**?

[image]

Comment: Where is the caster in this question?

Comment: @brandon, this _is_ the question

Comment: Ah, you're uncertain where the caster can be to place a given line. Maybe the question should be reworded to make that clearer? Something like "I am still unsure where the caster can (be to) place a line."

Comment: @András what do you find missing in the current answers that you are looking for more? I don't think there are more rules references than those referred to here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Any adjacent square except the first square of the effect is viable

The rules on [Areas](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=354) and its subsections is enlightening about the context of the words used within the section. Specifically, Cone has rules that seem relevant to parsing the (very limited) words relating to Lines.

> A cone shoots out from you in a quarter circle on the grid. When you aim a cone, the first square of that cone must share an edge with your space if you’re aiming orthogonally, or it must touch a corner of your space if you’re aiming diagonally. If you’re Large or larger, the first square can run along the edge of any square of your space. You can’t aim a cone so that it overlaps your space. [...]

Then, applying to context that "shoot[ing] out" has these restrictions for Cones, it seems likely that

> A line shoots forth from you in a straight line in a direction of your choosing. The line affects each creature whose space it overlaps. [...]

would have similar rule implications.

- the first square must share must touch a corner of your space
- you can choose any corner of your space (see the 15ft diagonal cone)
- you can't aim (a no-range) effect to hit your own square

---

Side note, *I* would be inclined against allowing aiming from the top-right space (C) because I don't feel like traveling along an adjacent square is "shoot[ing] forth", but the other established rules seem to disagree, mechanically speaking. My tables have not had to rule either way on this, in play.

Answer (score 3):

### Casting from any adjacent square would be fine

> A line shoots forth from you in a straight line in a direction of your choosing. The line affects each creature whose space it overlaps. Unless a line effect says otherwise, it is 5 feet wide. For example, the lightning bolt spell’s area is a 60-foot line that’s 5 feet wide.

The [line](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=358) "shoots forth from you" (emits from you), so I'd say it can start from any corner of the grid that borders you. Line effects always emit from corners of squares as shown in the diagram.

Then it can be a straight line in any direction of your choosing. "Shoots forth from you" could be interpreted as requiring the line to move away from you, but the further text "in a direction of your choosing" suggests that it just means the line has to start from you.

Note that there isn't any provision preventing the caster from choosing to catch themselves like with [cones](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=356). This parallels the difference between cones/emanations emitting from a square and lines/bursts emitting from a corner when using a grid.